# Select Random cell that is not Blank

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am having a problem that my brain cannot figure out.

I have a script that I copied and modified that will Randomly select a cell that is not blank from reassign!A1:A10

in reassign Tab I have a Query that will filter another sheet if a checkbox is ticked

so in reassign!A1:A10 it will depend if how many checkbox are ticked

the output is it only selects the first cell which is A1

Script:

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("reassign");
  var range = sheet.getRange("A1:A10");
  var values = range.getValues();
  var newValue = "";

  for(var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    if(values[i][0] != "") {
      newValue = values[i][0];
      break;
    }

  }

  sheet.getRange("B2").setValue(newValue);
}
```

I am running out of ideas. Sorry

Thanks in advance

I tried researching for solutions, but I really can't figure it out.

Comment: Hello! What's your expected outcome?? Could you share a sample??

Comment: Hi! , Sorry for the crappy explanation. the outcome I expect is the script will randomly select a non blank cell in reassign!A1:A10 and put the selected value to B2.

Answer (score 0):

The explanation that you have provide is not clear to me at all.  But perhaps this small change might make a difference.

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("reassign");
  var range = sheet.getRange("A1:A10");
  var values = range.getValues();
  var newValue = "";
  for(var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    if(values[i][0] !== "") {
      newValue = values[i][0];
      break;
    }
  }
  sheet.getRange("B2").setValue(newValue);
}
```

Random Selection of non blank values:

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("reassign");
  var range = sheet.getRange("A1:A10");
  var values = range.getValues().flat().filter(e => e);
  sheet.getRange("B2").setValue(values[Math.floor(Math.random() * values.length)]);
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the crappy explanation. What I mean is, the script will randomly select a cell in reassign!A1:A10 that is not blank and put it in B2

But my script only selects the first cell it doesn't select randomly. 

I also have here a script that will select randomly but sometimes it selects the blank cells

I will provide the other script in an answer.

Comment: Random Selection of non blank values did the trick. But sometimes it selects itself again. 
Example 
Staff 1,
Staff 2,
Staff 3,
Staff 4,

the script selected Staff 4 when I run it again sometimes it selected Staff 4 again. 
but anyways thank you so much for the effort. 

I will try to figure this thing out.

Comment: Hi cooper, I added my version is this optimal or correct? I added an if statement so it will not select it self

Comment: Yeah that seems okay to me.

Comment: @Debz, I think it's typically more appropriate for you to write your own answer than edit this one.

Comment: I'm sorry. I'm kinda new to programming and stackoverflow. sorry for being inappropriate, will not do it again.

Answer (score 0):

This Script selects randomly but sometimes it selects blank cells

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("reassign");
  var range = sheet.getRange("A1:A10");
  var values = range.getValues();
  var newValue = values[Math.floor(Math.random()*values.length)][0];
  sheet.getRange("B2").setValue(newValue);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not at the PC right now, but you may try to add this line before var newValue.....:

```
values = values.filter(function (n) {return (n != "")})
```